# Size of form when run not equal to size in designer

Tags: c#, winforms

My form in designer have size 1946, 876, but when runtime, size of form is very small, equal 2/3 of designer. So it can't display all the controls in the panel. How can I display the correct size of the design or drag the form?

in design

[image]

[image]

when runtime
[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the size of the form is changed at run-time?

Comment: [AutoscaleMode.Font](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50201741/1997232)?

Comment: Your app is not DpiAware. Set `AutoScaleMode = Dpi`, follow the link in the first comment of the question Sinatr posted, apply that. Make sure you design at 100% scale.

Comment: This looks like either a dpi or autoscale issue. it might help to make sure that no autoscale is enabled in form properties, and either make the app is dpi-aware or force windows do not apply dpi scaling to the application.